# How to run an animation once on react-native

Tags: animation, react-native

I would like when you press a button, the animation runs with the `setState` of `btnLoaded` that goes to `true`, for that's good but I would like that once the animation was done, when click on the buttons, the animation is not executed anymore because it has already been launched and finished.

I do not see how to do that.

Here is the function of animation:

```
startButtonAnimation = () => {

    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    if (this.state.btnLoaded) {

        Animated.timing(
            this.animatedValue,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.bezier(0.15, 0.73, 0.37, 1.2)
            }
        ).start();

   }}
```

And the code of button:

```
<TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.9}
    onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
            btnLoaded: true
    });
    setTimeout(() => this.startButtonAnimation(), 50);

}}>
```

Code in action :

[image: Animation start any time to click to button]

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html):

> Animations are started by calling start() on your animation. start() takes a completion callback that will be called when the animation is done.

This:

```
    startButtonAnimation = () => {

    this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
    if (!this.state.btnLoaded) {
        this.setState({
            btnLoaded: true, 
        });
        Animated.timing(
            this.animatedValue,
            {
                toValue: 1,
                duration: 500,
                useNativeDriver: true,
                easing: Easing.bezier(0.15, 0.73, 0.37, 1.2)
            }
        ).start(() => {

    }};
...

   <TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.9}
    onPress={() => {
        setTimeout(() => this.startButtonAnimation(), 50);
    }}
    >
```

might do it. You should add more of your code to better understand what's going on.

Comment: hello, it can't work because on the button onPress the state is set to true each time

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and tell you that I haven't completely understood all of your issue as the code is quite limited: could you add a little bit more code of how your "button" is actually handled and specifically how you're displaying the border? Is it by evaluating btnLoaded? 

Having more of an idea of what's going on will help.

Comment: I have 10/20/30 buttons that can perform the same animation function. I want that as soon as one of the buttons has been pressed, the animation can not be replayed. Only once

Answer (score 0):

By using `this.animatedValue.setValue(0);`, you restart the animation to 0. If you put this code outside of your button's callback, then the animation, even if restarted, will be already to its `toValue` (1 here), so it won't run again.